# Subscript out of range when filling data in string array

Tags: vba, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to store some reference data in a string array and then use that later on to compare with another string array. However, the code is not working since I'm getting a "subscript out of range" error (see code comment below).

```
Sub StoreBaseReferences()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim val As Variant
    Dim stringValues() As String
    Dim i, rowCounter, columnCounter As Integer

    rowCounter = 0
    columnCounter = 0
    For i = 2 To Sheets("sheet").UsedRange.rows.Count

        For Each cell In Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 4))
            stringValues(rowCounter, columnCounter) = cell.Value 'this is throwing the subscript ouf of range error
            columnCounter = columnCounter + 1
        Next cell

        rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
        columnCounter = 0
    Next i
    MsgBox (stringValues(0, 0))


End Sub
```

What is missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays in VBA need to be dimensioned with the number of elements that are expected to be used.  You've defined the dimension, but not specified how many elements will be added to it.  Try adding the following line just before the For loop:

```
ReDim stringValues(Sheets("sheet").UsedRange.Rows.Count, 3)
```

Comment: Hi Joe, Thanks for the feedback. I understand Sheets("sheet").UsedRange.Rows.Count would give me the number of elements for x-axis. The 3 you specified the number of elements for y-axis. Can't we specify the dimension already when we declare the variable using Dim?

Comment: If you want to specify the number of elements in the `Dim` statement, then you have to use a constant value (i.e., `StringValues(10,3)`).  In this case, the number of y elements is dependent on the side of UsedRange, so you need to use ReDim since it's not a constant value.

Answer (score 1):

you are declaring a 1d array `Dim stringValues() As String`

but trying to use it as a 2d array `stringValues(rowCounter, columnCounter)`

Also, you are not declaring the size of the array and you are trying to use it. In VBA you have to make sure you tell the size of the array at the declaration time.

To delcare the count of elements that the array is capable of storing

`Dim stringArray(0 to 10)` or `Dim stringArray(10)`

and when iterating the counter starts at `0`.

Using `ReDim stringValues()` allows you to resize the bounds at a later stage.

The topic is too broad to go over in one answer so check out the links to learn out how to dimension your array

- [VBA arrays](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbaarrays.htm)
- [Array in Excel VBA](http://excelvbatutor.com/vba_chp21.htm)